# Solving $|\operatorname{Aut}(H)|=|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Couple of days ago, i actually asked this question : [Existence of a normal subgroup with $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}{(H)}\rvert>\vert\operatorname{Aut}{(G)}\rvert$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/existence-of-a-normal-subgroup-with-authautg).

I was thinking about the converse of this statement. Suppose $G$ is a finite group, with subgroups $H$ and satisfies $$|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|=|\operatorname{Aut}(H)|,$$ then can anything be said about, $H$ or $G$ in terms of their structure. Will $H$ be normal or ....? Or one can even ask, that find all finite groups $G$ such that $|\operatorname{Aut}(H)|=|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$ for every subgroup $H$ of $G$! I am not interested that much in this question as there seems one can have lot of Groups of this type, but i am more curious to know the behaviour of $H$.

Also, anyone interested can very well read this article in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/order-of-an-automorphism-of-a-finite-group

Comment: I'd be amazed if there was anything general that
could be said about this situation. But here's an example
where it holds. For most values of $n$, $S_n$
and $A_n$ have the same order of automorphism group.

Comment: In the group $C_2\times C_4 \times S_3$, the subgroup $H=C_2\times C_4\times C_2$ satisfies this property, but is not normal.

Comment: @Robin Chapman: Please provide me with proof of that result, between $S_{n}$ and $A_{n}$.

Comment: @Chandru1: See pages 299ff in Suzuki's "Group Theory", vol. 1.

Comment: @Steve D: For my problem or the one which Robin Chapman had stated.

Comment: @Chandru1: I mean a proof of Robin's statement. I doubt very much there is anything interesting to say about such group/subgroup pairs, as relates to your original question.

Comment: @Steve D: Ok steve, thanks. If supposing i invoke, some condition do you think that it can be solved. For example $H$ is abelian....something like that

Answer (score 1):

In response to:

> ...find all finite groups $G$ such that $|\mathrm{Aut}(H)|=|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$ for every subgroup $H$ of $G$

the only groups (finite or infinite) for which this is true is the trivial group and the group of order $2$.

*Proof*: All groups have the trivial group $\{1\}$ as a subgroup, which has a trivial automorphism group, i.e., $|\mathrm{Aut}(\{1\})|=1$.  By the assumptions on $G$, we have $|\mathrm{Aut}(\{1\})|=|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|=1$.  The only groups with $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|=1$ are the trivial group and the group of order $2$ ([ref.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Trivial_automorphism_group_implies_trivial_or_order_two)).  The property is true for these two groups.

Comment: Aren't statements like this usually read with an implicit 'nontrivial' just to avoid this sort of pedantry?  E.g., talking about simple groups as 'those with no normal subgroups'...

Comment: I have spent like 10 minutes on this, but suppose $G$ is finite with $ \#G \geq 2$. Consider the prime factorisation of $ \#G$ and note that for every prime $p \mid \#G$ there is a subgroup $H_p$ of order $p$ by Cauchy's theorem. In particular, each $H_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and, hence, $|\text{Aut}(H_p)| = |U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})| = p-1$. This leaves only the groups of prime order?

Comment: Even without including the trivial subgroup, any cyclic subgroup of order $p$ has automorphism group of size $p-1$.  So if $|G|$ is divisible by two primes, you're out of luck.  If $G$ is a p-group, looking at $G/\Phi(G)$ shows it would have to be cyclic.  A quick count then shows $G$ would have to be cyclic of prime order.