# Automorphisms of the affine semilinear group $A\Gamma L(1,2^{n})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, semidirect-product

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/existence-of-a-normal-subgroup-with-operatornameauth-operatornameau) question, it is mentionned that the group of automorphisms of the semilinear group $A\Gamma L(1,2^{n})$ is the group itself.

Do you have a short proof of this fact?

Comment: This is false for $n=1$. But it is is true for all prime powers $q>2$, not just powers of $2$. It is not too hard to show directly that ${\rm Aut(AGL}(1,q)) \cong {\rm Aut(A \Gamma L}(1,q))$. That reduces to showing that any automorphism preserves both the additive and the multiplicative structure of the field. But I am not going to write down the details! Then you could prove the result by showing that ${\rm AGL}(1,q)$ is characteristic in ${\rm A \Gamma L}(1,q)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Derek, without asking you to write down all the details, can you elaborate on what you mean by "any automorphism preserves both the additive and the multiplicative structure of the field"? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G={\rm AGL}(1,q)$ is the group of transformations of $K={\mathbb F}_q$ of the form $x \to ax+b$ with $a \in K$, $0 \ne b \in K$. It is generated by the translations $\tau_a:x \to x+a$ and the multiplications $\mu_b:x \to bx$. Note that $\mu_b\tau_a\mu_b^{-1}=\tau_{ab}$.

Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of $G$. The translation group is characteristic (it is a normal Sylow subgroup of $G$) and hence is fixed by $\phi$. So we can write $\phi(\tau_a) = \tau_{\psi(a)}$ where $\psi$ as is a permutation of $K$ induced by $\phi$. Since $\phi$ fixes the identity of $G$, we have $\psi(0)=0$. Also, by composing $\phi$ with the inner automorphism induced by $\mu_b$ for some $b$, we can assume that $\psi(1)=1$.

We claim that $\psi$ is an automorphism of $K$, which will prove that ${\rm Aut}(G)={\rm A \Gamma L}(1,q)$.

$\psi(a_1+a_2)=\psi(a_1) + \psi(a_2)$ follows from $\phi(\tau_{a_1}\tau_{a_2}) = \phi(\tau_{a_1})\phi(\tau_{a_2})$.

Now, since $\psi(1)=1$, $\phi$ must fix the stabilizer in $G$ of $1 \in K$, which the multiplication group of elements $\mu_b \in G$. Then $$\phi(\mu_b)\tau_1\phi(\mu_b^{-1}) = \phi(\mu_b)\phi(\tau_1)\phi(\mu_b^{-1}) = \phi(\mu_b\tau_1\mu_b^{-1}) = \phi(\tau_{b}) = \tau_{\psi(b)}=\mu_{\psi(b)}\tau_1\mu_{\psi(b)}^{-1}$$
implies that $\phi(\mu_b) = \mu_{\psi(b)}$, and then $\psi(b_1b_1)=\psi(b_1)\psi(b_2)$ follows from $\phi(\mu_{b_1}\mu_{b_2}) = \phi(\mu_{b_1})\phi(\mu_{b_2})$.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!