# What is $\rm{Aut}(\rm{AGL}(1,q))$ for $q=p^r$ and $r > 1$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, linear-transformations

Let's $K$ be a finite field with $q=p^r$ elements where $p$ prime is the characteristic of $K$.

We denote $\rm{AGL}(n,q)$ the affine general linear group of dimension $n$ over $K$. I'm trying to identify $\rm{Aut}(\rm{AGL}(1,q))$.

$\rm{AGL}(n,q)$ is isomorphic to $K^* \times K$ equipped with the operation $$(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1 a_2,a_2 b_1 + b_2).$$ I computed the $m$-th power of an element $(a,b)$ which is $$(a,b)^m=\begin{cases}
(1,mb) & \text{for } a=1\\
(a^m,b \frac{a^m-1}{a-1}) & \text{for } a \neq 1
\end{cases}$$ From there I induce that an element $(1,b)$ with $b \neq 0$ is having order $p$. The order of an element $(a,b)$ with $a \neq 1$ is equal to the order of $a$ in $K^*$.

But I'm having hard time to move from there...

*Note: this is a question I raise following [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581985/automorphisms-of-the-affine-semilinear-group-a-gamma-l1-2n).*

Comment: So from Derek Holt's comment you know that the answer is $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf F_q) \ltimes \mathsf{AGL}(1,q)$ but you are asking for a proof?

Comment: So if I understand that comment correctly this is more or less what you should do: observe that $G = \mathrm{Aut}(\mathsf{AGL}(1,q))$ acts on the characteristic subgroup $(K,+)$ (it is in fact the unique Sylow-p-subgroup I think), i.e. on the affine line. Of course every automorphism $\alpha$ will fix $0$ and there should exist an inner automorphism $i_g$ such that $\alpha i_g$ fixes $1$. From there it should apparently be possible to conclude that $\alpha i_g$ preserves the field structure, hence originates from $\zeta \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb F_q)$ and then $\alpha = \zeta i_g^{-1}$...

Comment: @Myself Yes, that is right. I'm having difficulties to derive the proof from Derek comment and I try to work directly on $\rm{Aut}(\rm{AGL}(1,q))$.